# Android POJO class check if particular key contains value as Boolean or arraylist

Tags: java, android, json, pojo, jsonserializer

I have JsonArraylist in which there are multiple jsonobjects.In one of jsonObject json key contains Boolean value and on other Jsonobject the same key contain ArrayList.
How to check in POJO class if key contains ArrayList or boolean value as i am getting error:

**W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 1927 path $[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ02v.png).tags**

The Json is:
[image]

My POJO class is :

```
public class Posts implements  Serializable
  String id;
String title;
boolean mIsBookmark;
ArrayList<WebTags>tags;

public ArrayList<WebTags> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(ArrayList<WebTags> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}


public boolean isBookmark() {
    return mIsBookmark;
}

public void setBookmark(boolean mIsBookmark) {
    this.mIsBookmark = mIsBookmark;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Webapps_post{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", date='" + date + '\'' +
            ", tags='"+ tags+'\'' +
            '}';
}
public class WebTags implements  Serializable
{
    String term_id;
    String name;

    public String getTerm_id() {
        return term_id;
    }

    public void setTerm_id(String term_id) {
        this.term_id = term_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "WebTags{"+
                "term_id='" + term_id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }}
}
```

Comment: Even if it is possible (maybe with a custom deserializer), what will "true" means for tags? If true will never happens, why not give an empty array instead of "false". Maybe you should first get the data as String and replace "tags:false" with "tags:[]" ...

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeAdapter` is exactly what you are looking for. To summarize you can add a custom conversion logic for a user defined datatype such as a `class` and the Gson serializer/deserializer is smart enough to do it based on the return type of the conversion methods

An example for the usage can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_custom_adapters.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom deserializer for class `Posts` like below:

```
class PostsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Posts> {

    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Posts {
        val finalResult = Posts()

        // manually set all elements (except 'tags') to finalResult object.
        //...
        // set tags element now
        val tagsElement = json.asJsonObject.get("tags")
        
        if(tagsElement?.isJsonArray == true) {
            finalResult.tags = context.deserialize(tagsElement, WebTags::class.java)
        } else {
            finalResult.tags = emptyList()
        }
        
        return finalResult
    }
}
```

The above code will tell the GSON library what to map when the tags field is an array or when the tags field is a boolean.

Comment: Where to put this code & how to call tags to get value using this code. As of now I am calling tags: 
`final Webapps_post model = mRecentPostList.get(position); String tagName=model.getTags().get(0).getName();`